# Do the different Kart pieces affect gameplay?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Do the kart types or different pieces you can choose affect gameplay at all? Do they affect speed/handling/etc.?

Or are they just aesthetic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each piece has certain stats associated with it.  You'll need to hit + on your Gamepad/Controller/Wiimote/whatever to see how it correlates to other pieces, though.

Comment: On a related note, many pieces do share stats with other pieces. The difference between these is entirely aesthetic.